# Mysql: Procedure call within Cursor declaration

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, cursor

I am attempting to use a MySql stored procedure call as part of my cursor declaration (to nest procedures and be able to view results):

```
declare myCursor cursor for call MyProcedure(param1,param2,param3);
```

When I do this though, I get the 1064 error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use.

Anyone know how to accomplish this?

Thank You

Comment: One more flaw of the MySQL procedure language :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/declare-cursor.html

Says:

> DECLARE cursor_name CURSOR FOR select_statement

`call` is not a **select_statement**.
That's why you're getting an error.

**Workaround**
If you're using a stored proc that returns a resultset, use the equivalent select statement instead.

**Problem**
The problem is that a `call` can return 0, 1 or more resultsets.
The cursor can only handle the 1 resultset case and AFAIK MySQL has no way to know for sure how many resultsets the call will return.

Comment: Ah, yes.  This is it.  And, there is no way to call a procedure from a select statement.  Thanks!

Comment: You can call a **function** from a select statement. And cheat like that. Function return single values though not resultsets.

Answer (score 1):

Here is how I did it:

Have the procedure return its resultset inside temporary table.

```
create procedure GetPeople(in unitId bigint(20))
begin

    create temporary table if not exists GetPeople_result like People;
    truncate table GetPeople_result;

    insert into GetPeople_result select * from
        -- your select here
    ;
end
```

Make cursor for the temporary table.

```
create procedure DoSomethingWithAllPeople(in unitId bigint(20))
begin

    declare allPeopleCursor cursor for select PersonId from GetPeople_result; -- select the result from GetPeople
    call GetPeople(unitId); -- create the GetPeople_result table and fill it

    -- iterate cursor

end
```